# OpenCV no longer opens video files VideoCapture

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, computer-vision

I have a problem seemingly caused by OpenCV 3.xx - the problem does not manifest in OpenCV 2.xx

The issue is reading video files. I've set my code up as follows:

```
>#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
>#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
>#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
>#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
>#include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>

>int main()

>    cv::VideoCapture cap;
>    cv::Mat frame;
>    if(!cap.open("Myfile.avi"))
>        std::cout << "Open failed" << std::endl;
>    else
>        cap.read(frame);
>
>    cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
>    cv::waitKey(5000);
>    return 0;
```

Now the problem is when the code gets to "cap.read(frame)" I get a "vector subscript is out of range" error with OpenCV 3.40 and this does not happen with my build of OpenCV 2.4.9. The format of the file is in avi, its not some weird codec, and clearly it works in previous versions of OpenCV.

I've tried other OpenCV 3.xx builds and I get the same or similar problems with simply reading a file in.

My question is twofold:
How do I get OpenCV 3.xx to work with reading video files (or do I need to regress to 2.xx?)

Why has the major revision change completely screwed up video file reading? That doesn't make any sense for a computer vision API.

As a guess it will be something to do with the FFMPEG implementation because various searches have turned up other people having issues with this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve it myself, it turns out that in OpenCV 3.xx I have to force the VideoCapture::open to use the FFMPEG library by doing this:

```
>cap.open("Myfile.avi", cv::CAP_FFMPEG)
```

where the latter parameter is the flags to identify which VideoCapture API backend to use. The list can be found here for any one else interested:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html